# Laravel unit testing with sqlite on Virtualbox does not work

Tags: sqlite, testing, laravel-5, virtualbox, laravel-dusk

Testing on Virtualbox with laravel dusk and using as test database sqlite I get

```
unlink(/var/www/laravel/database/database.sqlite): Text file busy
```

after researches I understand this problem is mainly because of Virtualbox shared folder.

I was trying to call the sqlite file from /tmp folder but in this case I get

```
Database (/tmp/database.sqlite) does not exists
```

How would I manage this issue to have my tests running

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should manually create file:

```
touch /tmp/database.sqlite
```

It's true, that using Virtualbox or Docker there might be issues with file sharing. I had `Text file busy` error many times. Usually to solve this you need to restart your VM to get rid of this error.

Comment: Thanks for feedback I will try now with a restart!